# Disable submit until all fields are valid in reactstrap

Tags: reactstrap

I have a form in reactstrap that has several input fields that uses FormFeedback like this:

```
<Input invalid={typeof data.name === "undefined" || data.name.length<1} bssize="sm" type="text" name="name" id="name" placeholder="Name" value={data.name} onChange={this.props.handleInputChange} />
<FormFeedback >A name is required</FormFeedback>

<Button color="primary" onClick={this.save} disabled={!this.state.okToSubmit}>Submit</Button>
```

Is it possible to have the submit button of the form disabled until all fields are validating ok?

I can´t find any way to access the "invalid" prop of a field. The closest I have come so far is to look at the classList of target in the handleInputChange-function. But that feels very hacky and not the best way.

Quite new to React so all help is really appreciated.

Comment: I don't think there is a better way than looking at the classList without using an extension. If you don't mind using one, there's this: https://availity.github.io/availity-reactstrap-validation/

Answer (score 1):

There are a number of ways you can accomplish this: Since you are using `onChange` event handler, you can set another state var.

So, for example, say you have five form elements that you want to have be `required`. Every time an element is validated, increase that state var by one. Then add a conditional for the button to be disabled or not by `disabled={this.state.okToSubmit != 5}` (this can also be done using hooks if you're using a functional component.

Another option would be to keep the button live, and do all the validation within the `onSubmit` handler, but I think most modern day UX is to validate on a per element basis.